# Ubuntuserver as router

Tags: linux, networking, router, ubuntu-server

As the title says I need some help in setting up my home network as I am not (yet) good at "networking".
So... what do I want to do? I just moved into a college dorm . I got a pretty good connection here by a lan port on the wall. I brought with me my PC and a Ubuntuserver which I want to use as my router, because I got no wifi here. So my question is what kind of additional network card(s) do I need? What do I have to look for in specs? Are there any guides for configurating the ubuntu server you could recommend that are easily to understand for a newbie (the ones I did find via google were incomplete or too old)? Besides that I want to let the server run his main task, a gameserver. I hope I was specific enough and you did understand what I want to build.
Thanks in advance!

[illustration of my wanted setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv7UT.png)

Comment: You should go out and buy an Ethernet router. They are cheap as chips and a lot easier then setting up an Ubuntu box as a router. By the time you have factored in power consumption and additional hardware its likely cheaper.

Comment: Eg tl-wr841n  (https://www.newegg.com/tp-link-tl-wr841n-ieee-802-11b-g-n/p/N82E16833704039 on special for $18) [the nano router I initially suggested does not have LAN ports, so no good to you]

Answer (score 0):

On your Ubuntu machine you'll need two wired network cards and a wireless card.  For the wireless card, you'll need to be sure that it has good drivers for Linux, and that those drivers (and the card itself) allow the card to be put into "access point mode" (AP mode).  As far as cabling, you'll need a CAT-5 cable from the wall to one of your NICs, and either a crossover cable OR network cards that support auto-sensing of traffic direction OR two straight through cables and a small switch or hub.

Personally I'd go with the switch model, skip the wireless card and instead get an access point and plug that into the switch as well.  At that point I'd probably also ditch the "ubuntu server" and use a Raspberry Pi in its place simply for power consumption and noise/heat control (actually I do that here at hte house, I use the Pi to control a separate subnet for my kids so I can do aggressive traffic shaping).  Plug your game server into the switch as well, and simply forward the appropriate port(s) in your `iptables` script.

Comment: May not be a good idea to go for a switch model as thus could limit use to 1 port or cause problems with conflicts on upstream connection, and exposing your LAN to attack.